# Update table based on another table

Tags: sql, sql-update

I'm trying to update a column in a table based on another column in another table.

```
UPDATE eval e
   SET rank = (SELECT p.desc
                 FROM Position p
                WHERE p.id = e.faculty 
                  AND p.date >= '2011-05-20'
              )
```

`p.id` and `e.faculty` correspond. I want to update rank with `p.desc` if the id's are the same. (`e.faculty` and `p.id`)

Any help will be great! :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try this for SQL Server:

```
UPDATE dbo.eval 
SET rank = p.desc
FROM dbo.Position p
WHERE p.id = eval.faculty and p.date >= '2011-05-20'
```

or if you need an alias on the base table (for whatever reason), you need to do this:

```
UPDATE dbo.eval 
SET rank = p.desc
FROM dbo.eval e
INNER JOIN dbo.Position p ON p.id = e.faculty 
WHERE p.date >= '2011-05-20'
```

Comment: Is there a way to use this syntax with an alias on the updated table?  For example, this is invalid: `UPDATE @Y SET Field = X.Field FROM @X AS X WHERE @Y.Key = X.Key`.  I'd normally use `UPDATE Y SET Field = X.Field FROM @Y AS Y INNER JOIN @X AS X ON Y.Key = X.Key`, but that's a little more verbose.

Comment: This should work for Postgresql, too, as a non-standard extension.

Comment: "update banks_info set state = s.guid FROM banks_info b inner join bank_states s on s.name = b.state"

I am trying this query, but not able to run this.

"#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM banks_info b inner join bank_states s on s.name = b.state' at line 1" any suggestions

Comment: I like the second query more, because you only change SELECT with UPDATE, so there is lower probability to make an error because most people I guess use JOIN by default so you don't need to rewrite it to old join for update reason.

Answer (score 2):

You need a restriction in the form of a `WHERE` clause; if you use `EXISTS` you can based it on you scalar subquery e.g.

```
UPDATE eval
   SET rank = (
               SELECT p.desc
                 FROM Position p
                WHERE p.id = eval.faculty 
                      AND p.date >= '2011-05-20'
              )
 WHERE EXISTS (
               SELECT *
                 FROM Position p
                WHERE p.id = eval.faculty 
                      AND p.date >= '2011-05-20'
              );
```

Note the above targets the `UPDATE` on the base table `eval` rather than the correlation name `e`. This makes a lot more sense when you think of an SQL `UPDATE` in terms of relational assignment i.e. you don't want to assign to `e` because it (unlike the base table) will go out of scope!